# ¿Cómo puede completar el nombre de una variable con otro variable usando funciones?

Tags: c++

Buen día, lo que pasa es que quisiera realizar cierta impresión n veces, pero con algunos aspectos diferentes cada vez que se imprima, de una forma en la que pueda ahorrarme el tener que copear y pegar la misma línea de impresión.
Realice el siguiente ejemplo para explicarme un poco mejor:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class Funcion{
    private:
        int numero1=10, numero2=20, numero3=30; 
    public:
        int imprimir(int);
};

int Funcion::imprimir(int a){
    cout<<numero(a);
}

int main(){
    Funcion caso;
    caso.imprimir(1);
    caso.imprimir(2);
    caso.imprimir(3)    
}
```

En la función `imprimir` simplemente quiero imprimir las variables que están previamente declaradas. Pero para no tener que escribir tres veces la misma linea, cambiándole el número, pensé que podría hacerlo cambiando ese ultimo dígito por una variable que vaya cambiando. Por eso en el `main` llamo la función con diferentes parámetro.
Lo que quisiera saber es, si hay alguna forma de concatenar a la variable `numero` la variable `a`.

**Nota:** Este es solo un ejemplo, ya se que estoy llamando la función tres veces, pero en un programa que estoy realizando, este método me ahorraría muchísimas lineas de código.

Agradecería una respuesta.

Comment: ¿ Hay algún motivo por el que no puedas usar formaciones (`variable[10]`) y/o/u contenedores ( `std::array< >`, `std::vector< >` ) ?

Comment: No entiendo tu pregunta, en el caso de `variable[10]` estaría declarándolo como array, no?

Comment: Pregunto que porqué en lugar de usar `variable1`, `variable2`, `variable3` no usas `variables[3]`. O no he entendido bien lo que quieres hacer, que también puede ser :-)

Comment: Una pregunta... la idea es imprimir siempre **todas** esas variables o elegir un conjunto de ellas cada vez?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes usar una macro:

```
#define IMPRIMIR(X) X.imprimir(1); X.imprimir(2); X.imprimir(3)
```

```
int main(){
    Funcion caso;
    IMPRIMIR(caso);
    return 0;
}
```

O una plantilla:

```
class Funcion{
    private:
        int numero1=10, numero2=20, numero3=30; 
    public:
        int imprimir(int);

        template <typename ... T>
        void imprimir(int v, T ... t)
        {
            imprimir(v);
            imprimir(t ...);
        }
};
```

```
int main(){
    Funcion caso;
    caso.imprimir(1,2,3);
    return 0;
}
```